# Выбор скриптового движка для JAVA проекта

Tags: java, разработка-игр, скрипт

Занимаюсь разработкой игры на java. В игре будет in game programming. Исходя из это никак не могу определится со скриптовым движком. Сейчас остановился на JNLua, но есть некоторые сложности с кросплатформенностью и управлением ресурсами система для движка. Необходимо обеспечить изолированность движка от системы и ограничить уровень нагрузки на систему со стороны последнего. Не хотелось бы чтоб игрок получил контроль над игровым сервером или вызвал проблемы с производительностью своим скриптом. Пока что lua видится лучшим вариантом.

Comment: Можете уточнить, что будет скриптоваться на движке и как? Условно говоря, это будут скрипты уровня 2+2, или тысячи строк кода. Какая мультиплатформенность примерно нужна?

Comment: Вся игровая механика завязана на программирование. скрип выполняется асинхронно, представляют os (оболочку) типа dos позволяющую взаимодействовать с виртуальной файловой системой и запускать собственно пользовательские скрипты, по завершению которых управление возвращается в оболочку. Как пример opencomputers, computercraft. Модель скриптов именно от туда. Модель встраивания скрипта в игровой цикл не хочу на пример как в Space Engineers или screeps. Платформы win/lin/mac